# Lightning node on a Bitcoin SPV

Tags: lightning-network, spv, lightning-network-daemon, thin-clients, core-lightning

is there a way to run a Lightning node on a Bitcoin SPV node at the moment? I've read that both lnd and c-lightning need a Bitcoin Fullnode at this time.
This might seem ignorant but i don't want to go through the hassle of syncing the whole chain for a small test setup right now. The Bitcoin Lightning Wallet for Android for example claims to run on a Bitcoin SPV so there has to be a way.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are lightweight LN wallets vulnerable to transaction withholding?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85557/are-lightweight-ln-wallets-vulnerable-to-transaction-withholding)

Answer (score 2):

LND is experimenting with the new Neutrino BIP157-style SPV at the moment. Check out their repo for news.

Both Bitcoin Lightning Wallet and Eclair on Android use a trusted server for syncing with the network.

BIP-37-style SPV is not a good choice for anyone (because of privacy issues), but particularly not for Lightning wallets, because it is very easy for an adversary to help a channel partner in cheating by withholding critical transactions that your wallet would have to respond to.